# What's the right way to reset / initialize InfiniteLoader

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-virtualized

I'm trying to use `InfiniteLoader` from the `react-virtualize` library to show up a scrollable list that has a `textSearch` input field on top (used to filter list entries).

The code I use is very close to the [InfiniteLoader Sample Code](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.example.js).
The list is working fine, but I'm not sure how to reset/initialize the `InfiniteLoader` when the `searchText` is changed and (completely) new data should be shown.

The flow is like this:

1. the list is opened for the first time and shows data from the `redux store` (works fine).
2. user changes `textSearch` and new data is fetched to the `store`
3. at this point, `InfiniteLoader` should be be initialized (I tried calling `resetLoadMoreRowsCache` on `InfiniteLoader`)
4. `InfiniteLoader` should call `loadMoreRows` like for the first time and rerender with the new data

I've seen that the [INFINITELOADER DEMO](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/InfiniteLoader) has the same behaviour: by clicking 'Flush Cached Data' nothing happens until I start scolling the list.

So my **question**: what is the right way to reset/initialize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For newer versions of `InfiniteLoader`

Since this question has been posted, `InfiniteLoader` has gained a parameter which auto-reloads the data. You can now use:

```
infiniteLoaderRef.resetLoadMoreRowsCache(true);
```

to automatically flush the cache and get new rows.

### For older versions of `InfiniteLoader`

`InfiniteLoader` reacts to a range of rows being rendered. The [`resetLoadMoreRowsCache` method](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L72-L74) just resets cached data. It doesn't automatically request a batch of rows be loaded.

Arguably it should. I don't know. It seemed easy enough for user code to auto-load the first batch of new data if the application state has changed in such a way as to require `resetLoadMoreRowsCache` to be called.

Anyway, tl;dr is that you should be able to do this:

```
infiniteLoaderRef.resetLoadMoreRowsCache(); // Reset the cache

loadMoreRows({ // Manually kick off the first batch
  startIndex: 0,
  stopIndex: 20 // Or whatever
});
```

Happy to review a PR to change the default behavior if you feel it could be improved.

Comment: thanks for your clarifications (and for this great library too!). your suggestions combined with a call to the `recomputeRowHeights` - method of `List` did it. thanks again

Comment: The method suggested above to reset the cache has been updated to allow for auto-reloading now, the new method signature is `resetLoadMoreRowsCache (autoReload: boolean = false)`. This removed the need to manually kick off the first batch as suggested in this answer.

Comment: Hi Hans I'd like to clarify what you are saying for other readers as I misinterpreted. The autoReload boolean being true will reload the previously data request so if you were in view of 40-60 it would reload 40-60 rather than 0-60.

Comment: There is also a prop now, `resetloadMoreItemsCache`, that takes a boolean parameter.